# EF 4 CTP 5: Trouble trying to remove an entity

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-ctp5, ef-code-first

I have created a model POCO class called `Recipe`; a corresponding `RecipeRepository` persists these objects. I am using Code First on top of an existing database.

Every `Recipe` contains an `ICollection<RecipeCategory>` of categories that link the `Recipes` and the `Categories` table in a many-to-many relationship. `RecipeCategory` contains the corresponding two foreign keys.

A simplified version of my controller and repository logic looks like this (I have commented out all checks for authorization, `null` objects etc. for simplicity):

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    _recipeRepository.Remove(id);

    return View("Deleted");
}
```

The repository's `Remove` method does nothing but the following:

```
public void Remove(int id)
{
    Recipe recipe = _context.Recipes.Find(id);
    _context.Recipes.Remove(recipe);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Howevery, the code above does not work since I receive a `System.InvalidOperationException` every time I run it: *Adding a relationship with an entity which is in the Deleted state is not allowed.*

What does the error message stand for and how can I solve the problem? The only thing I try to achieve is deleting an entity.

---

@Ladislav: I have replaced `ICollection<RecipeCategory>` by `ICollection<Category>`. Accidentially, ReSharper refactored away the `virtual` keyword.

However, the problem remains — I cannot delete a `Category` from a `Recipe` entity. The following code does not persist the deletion of the categories to the database:

```
private void RemoveAllCategoriesAssignedToRecipe()
{
    foreach (Category category in _recipe.Categories.ToArray())
    {
        _recipe.Categories.Remove(category);
        category.Recipes.Remove(_recipe);
    }

    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I have debugged the code and can confirm that the collections are modified correctly — that is, they contain no elements after the loop (I have also used the `Clear()` method). After calling `SaveChanges()`, they are populated again.

What am I doing wrong?

(Maybe it is important: I am using the Singleton pattern to only have one instance of the context.)

Comment: Are you sure that only this code is executed? This error usually means that your recipe has some pending relation to category which hasn't been saved yet. Also Find method is able to load entity from DbContex's internal storage and only if it doesn't find it, it query database. When do you instantiate your DbContext? Another thing: Why Recipe contains ICollection<RecipeCategory> instead of ICollection<Category>?

Comment: @Ladislav: Please refer to my updated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem the following way:

```
private void RemoveAllCategoriesAssignedToRecipe()
{
    foreach (Category category in _recipe.Categories.ToArray())
    {
        Category categoryEntity = _categoryRepository.Retrieve(category.CategoryID);

        var recipesAssignedToCategory = categoryEntity.Recipes.ToArray();
        categoryEntity.Recipes.Clear();

        foreach (Recipe assignedRecipe in recipesAssignedToCategory)
        {
            if (assignedRecipe.RecipeID == _recipe.RecipeID)
            {
                continue;
            }

            categoryEntity.Recipes.Add(assignedRecipe);
        }

        _context.Entry(categoryEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    _recipe.Categories.Clear();
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```